# Social Networking - What is the best strategy for collecting re-shared posts

Tags: php, mysql, social-networking

I am working on a social network database (MySQL) at which users can re-share other's posts. Each user could be followed by other users, hence other users would see his/her own posts plus posts re-shared by that user (with a reference to the original post) ordered by date (re-share or publish).

I considered two *Table* designs for this purpose:

**Design 1. using 2 tables**

`posts_tbl`:

- id (Primary, A_I)
- owner_id (a reference to `id` field of `users_tbl`)
- last_update (timestamp)
- time_created (timestamp)

`reshares_tbl`:

- id (Primary, A_I)
- src_owner_id (a reference to `id` field of `users_tbl`)
- resharer_id (a reference to `id` field of `users_tbl`)
- src_post_id (a reference to `id` field of `posts_tbl`)
- reshare_time

In this design, after re-sharing a post, a row would be added to `reshares_tbl`.

**Design 2. using 1 table**

`posts_tbl`:

- id (Primary, A_I)
- owner_id (a reference to `id` field of `users_tbl`)
- **type** (reshared or published)
- **src_id** (a reference to original post `id` field of `posts_tbl` if type = reshared)
- last_update (timestamp)
- time_created (timestamp)

In this design, after resharing a post, a row would be added to `posts_tbl`.

---

Which design is better? Is there a better way to do that?

Note: PHP is used for the back-end development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with your second approach. You don't need `type` though. Just check if `src_id` (which I would call `parent_id` (maybe someone is resharing a reshared post )) is not 0. Publish original posts with a parent id of 0, which would mean it's an original published post.

If `parent_id` has a value other than 0, which would be the id of the original post it's a reshared post. By adding a type (at least if you only have two types of posts to determine if it's an original post or a reshared one) you're creating redundancies which should be avoided in any case.

Comment: thanks - Wouldn't increasing the number of rows in the table `posts_tbl` (in second design) rise any problem?

Comment: in which way? Please explain your chain of thoughts to me please :)

Comment: I worry about db performance issues due to a marked increase in the number of rows !!

Comment: maintaining a seperate table for reshared posts would cause a much bigger overhead than using one table (at least, in your case), so your second approach is defenitely the way to go. Also think of the logical flaws. In your first approach one wouldn't be able to reshare a reshared post (since it does not exist in the regular post table)

Comment: @yaa110 i think increasing the number of rows has is not a problem, and a re-shared post is itself a post, but think to avoid a lot of null values in your re-shared rows

Comment: @medBo how would it come to a lot of null values if he uses that second approach?

Comment: @yaa110 if you have for example lot of columns in your posts_tbl like content, image_url, ... say 9 other columns, when you re-share a post you don't need to copy all these values, so the src_id or parent_id is sufficient as a reference to the original post, and the other columns will be null, but i think this is not your case

Comment: Oh noes! Don't do that please. Create a `posts_meta` table where stuff like the posts texts, images, etc. are stored.

Comment: @medBo - As @Thomas said I think I'd better create another table (such as `posts_meta`) and put all contents in it.

Comment: @yaa110 yes this is also a good choice :) good luck for the rest